Analyzing Diode Quartet Switch
I am trying to understand how this diode quartet switch works. I am having trouble dealing with the two current sources. I can think about what happens to the voltages in the circuit, but how do I logically incorporate the current sources?

Edit:
The circuit is from old lecture notes from a circuit design class I am taking. Unfortunately there's not really much more information given there. Here's a translation of what's in there:

Silicon diodes are often used as switches for SC applications. The decisive disadvantage of the diode as a switch is its voltage drop when switched on (silicon approx. 0.6V, Schottky 0.3V) and the electrical connection between the switching and switched circuit.
Both effects can be avoided to a certain extent by using a diode quartet in a bridge circuit.

Then it also says:

If Uc=high, there is an off-side (approximate) connection between the terminals Uin and Uout.


Please link to the document where you found the image for more context.

Axodarap, I second @Andyaka 's comment. Context matters and a single copy of a single behavioral diagram doesn't quite cut it. Also, don't worry about language differences. We can ferret that out with tools that are now widely available. Or, you can translate for us, if needed. (That would be better.) I think all of us can make some assumptions. But it is better if you help us avoid as many of those as possible. Regardless, write more.

sorry for that, i updated what I found

The current sources serve the same purpose as pull-up and pull-down resistors in a digital circuit: They pull the voltage on the connected node in a certain direction when it would otherwise become disconnected from the rest of the circuit, thereby providing a bias that turns one or more of the connected diodes on.
For proper operation of this circuit, the amplitude of \$U_{in}\$ must be much lower than \$\pm5V\$. Additionally, the current \$I\$ must be much larger than the current sunk by the load resistor at the maximum amplitude of \$U_{in}\$.
In the first case, let's assume that the comparator outputs \$-5V\$. Let's also assume that a diode drops \$700mV\$ when it conducts. The voltage put out by the comparator is lower than any signal voltages potentially present in the diode quartet, which means that the topmost horizontal diode conducts, putting the top node of the diode quartet at \$-4.3V\$. The amplitude of \$U_{in}\$ is much lower than that, which means that the voltages in the diode quartet will never get low enough to make its top two diodes conduct. The current \$I\$ is "stolen" by the horizontal diode, preventing it from flowing through the diode quartet.
Things look similar in the lower part of the circuit: The inverter puts out \$+5V\$, which means that the horizontal diode at the bottom of the circuit conducts. This similarly pushes the voltage at the bottom of the diode quartet up to \$+4.3V\$, which is higher than \$U_{in}\$ will ever reach, in turn making the bottom two diodes of the quartet never conduct and again "stealing" \$I\$.
As a result, the output is disconnected from the input.
With some crude GIMP annotations, that looks something like this:

The other case occurs when the comparator outputs \$+5V\$. As that voltage is larger than any voltage that might ever be present in the diode quartet, the topmost horizontal diode is reverse-biased. Similarly, the inverter outputs \$-5V\$, and it follows from the same argument that the bottom horizontal diode is also reverse-biased.
As a result, the diode quartet and its current sources are essentially "left alone" by the surrounding circuitry in this case. This means that the currents \$I\$ must now find a different path to flow through. Assuming that the load doesn't draw too much current, we can use the symmetry of the circuit to deduce that the current must split approximately equally between the two possible paths down the quartet. This means that all four diodes in the quartet are now conducting.
In the end, this connects \$U_{out}\$ to \$U_{in}\$, making the diode quartet a form of analog switch.
Again, with my crude GIMP skills, that'll look like this:

TL;DR: The circuit uses the horizontal diodes to steer the current \$I\$ so that it either flows through the diode quartet (conducting state) or not (isolating state) to build a bidirectional analog switch.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. I could follow mostly. I still don't quite get the curent sources though. It's the curretn sources that are resposnible for turning the horizontal diodes on/off?

@Axodarap The key is that the current sources provide power to bias the diodes without forcing a fixed voltage. The upper current source together with its three connected diodes, for example, will supply power to whatever diode "offers" the lowest voltage on its cathode. Without the current source, no current would flow at all and all of the diodes would always be off. The circuit uses control voltages to steer the bias current where it's needed, and it's the current that turns the selected diode(s) on.

So if i but a diode right after a current source, that current source will then provide the needed voltage such that my desired current flows?

@Axodarap Yes, that's one way to put it. Or in other words: A voltage source forces a certain voltage across a circuit and lets the current develop naturally (it provides as much current as needed to achieve the desired voltage). A current source forces a certain current through a circuit and lets the voltage develop naturally (it provides as much voltage as needed to achieve the desired current). It's exactly analogous, just with voltage and current flipped.

Some history
This weird circuit solution reminded me of the 70's when as a student studying Analog Circuits at a technical university I was struggling to understand what kind of madness this was (unfortunately, my teacher gave us ready-made circuit solutions and analyzed them with a bunch of formulas). Leaving aside the question of why there were all those diodes, the main question that bothered me was how the current from the input source passed through a diode in the reverse direction (there was always one in the current path) to reach the load. Also I had come up with the absurd idea that a turned on diode would somehow pass (at least AC) current in both directions like a piece of wire -:)
Basic idea
Diode shifting down
Later I thought about how a diode can shift voltage variations. I could understand how it could drop the voltage by 0.7 V (as a side effect in diode rectifiers) but I could not understand how it would raise the voltage by that much. I guess then I thought that the diode was a 0.7 V battery -:) as it was presented in textbooks.
Diode shifting up?
I only began to understand what was going on when I realized that the current was flowing in the opposite direction through the input source, i.e. it was going into it (if positive) instead of going out as I had expected. And for this to happen, the source had to allow current to flow in the opposite direction through it. Here is how I illustrated it in one of my yellowed records from my early 90's circuit idea archive (in Bulgarian); the translation is below the picture.

July 10, 1992. Shifting potential with an RD circuit, "lifting". Usually, a diode (p-n junction) lowers the voltage by Ud = 0.7 V. "Lifting" requires an additional source that causes the current I. In other words, the diode lowers the voltage E to Uin + Ud, "ties" it to Uin. The current I acts as a discharge on Uin (Uin must be able to "suck" it through its output).
Passive voltage compensation
Until then, the diode voltage drop was something harmful, bad, unwanted... but I started to see circuit solutions (for example in the Art of Electronics) where it was used for something useful - to compensate for the harmful diode drop.
This idea greatly interested me and I added it as a general principle (passive compensation) to my collection of circuit principles that I had begun to create. Later I was fascinated by the more advanced active compensation idea implemented with operational amplifiers in precision diode rectifiers.
Main idea
So the main idea in this circuit solution is to compensate the unwanted diode voltage drop by adding the same diode voltage in series.
The other two ideas are how to bias the diodes and how to control them but let's focus on the main idea.
Implementing by voltage sources
We can illustrate it in the simplest way by simulating the diodes through constant voltage sources. Since the circuits below are conceptual and their role is to reveal the main idea, I have chosen simplified values ​​of the voltages (whole numbers, if possible multiples of 10). That is why I have assumed that the forward diode voltage is 1 V. To simplify these conceptual diagrams at this initial stage, I have used a voltmeter as a high-resistive load (no load current) but at any point we can set some resistance to it.
No shifting
If the input source is connected directly to the load, the entire input voltage is applied to it.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The input and output voltage graphs match (they are on top of each other).

Shifting down
If an opposite source V- (a forward-biased diode) is connected in series, its voltage is subtracted from the input and the remainder appears across the load. So the voltage V- is something undesired, a loss.

simulate this circuit

Shifting down and up
In life, we compensate for harmful (negative) things with equivalent beneficial (positive) things. So we think of adding a voltage V+ with the same value as V- but with the same polarity as the input voltage.

simulate this circuit
In this way, 1 V is lost but 1 V is gained and the voltage across the load is again equal to the input voltage.

Shifting up
Conversely, if a voltage source V+ is connected in series so that its voltage is added to the input voltage, their amount will appear across the load. But again this voltage V+ is undesired for us.

simulate this circuit

Shifting up and down
So we connect an opposite source V-; its voltage is subtracted from the sum, and again the input voltage appears across the load.

simulate this circuit

Shifting both
Finally, if the input voltage is both upshift (by V+1) and downshift (by V-1) we can apply the same trick as both downshift (by V-2) and upshift (by V+2) it.

simulate this circuit
So the load voltage is equal to the input voltage.

Implementing by diodes
Now we just need to replace the voltage sources with diodes and bias them properly. A simple way to do it is through resistors connected to additional supply voltages V+ (positive) and V- (negative).
70s circuit
It is easiest to control these diode switches via electromechanical switches SW1 and SW2 connected in series with the resistors (this is how it was done in my circuit from the 70's).
Both SW1 and SW2 on: The input voltage appears unchanged across the load because it is "shifted up" by D+1 and "shifted down" by D-2 and also shifted down by D-1 and shifted up by D+2.

simulate this circuit

Both SW1 and SW2 off: The input voltage does not pass because at least one of every two diodes connected in series is off.

simulate this circuit

OP's circuit
A more reliable way to turn off the diodes is by applying a high (5 V) reverse voltage. That is how it is done in the OP's circuit. We can also improve the circuit by replacing the resistors with current sources.
Both SW1 and SW2 off: All diodes are on so the input voltage passes through the 4-diode switch.

simulate this circuit

Both SW1 and SW2 on: All diodes are off so the input voltage does not pass through the diode switch.

simulate this circuit

Where do currents flow?
The currents in the entire circuit are of interest, but I will highlight only one very important fragment. To cause a current to flow through the load RL (the voltmeter), I have deliberately reduced its resistance to 1 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
Voltage sources
When two equal but opposite voltsge sources (V+ and V-) are connected in series, their voltages cancel and the current in the circuit is the same as above.

simulate this circuit
Unbiased diodes
This is what I could not figure out as a student at one time - how current would flow through a backward-biased diode (D+); and it really does not pass.

simulate this circuit
Biased diodes
When a biasing current source I is connected, its current splits, and actually there are two currents - Iin and Iout, flowing through the diodes.

simulate this circuit
Why four diodes?
The last schematic makes us ask ourselves this logical question. My explanation is this:
In order for the two diodes to be forward-biased, they must be connected via some "pulling" elements (resistors, current sources) to the power source. The problem, however, is that when the analog switch is off (the diodes are backward-biased), the input source will be connected through these "pull" elements to the load. So, the second pair of (backward-biased) diodes is needed to break this connection.

I have created an enhanced version of this answer in a dialog with artificial intelligence.
